# Jasmine can't run specs inside Javascript prototype methods

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, prototype

I'm just starting to use Jasmine for unit testing of my JavaScript code, and I discovered that if I define a suite or a spec via `describe()` or `it()` inside of a prototype method of an object, it isn't recognized as a spec on the SpecRunner html page.

Is there any way around this? Because all of my code is written via prototype objects/methods and if I can't test inside of those, then I can't test anything and Jasmine is pretty much useless to me. Also, if not, are there any good unit-testing frameworks for JS that do work in prototype methods/etc?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you're unable to run specs _defined inside of a prototype method_, not that you're unable to run specs _about a prototype method_. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily test methods defined on objects' prototypes using jasmine.  Consider a basic Person object.

```
function Person(name)
{
  this._name = name;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function()
{
  return this._name;
};
```

To test the getName function, use the following.

```
describe('Person test suite', function()
{
  it('tests getName', function()
  {
    var p = new Person('Joe');
    expect(p.getName()).toBe('Joe');
  });
});
```

You can also spy on a method that's on an object's prototype.  For example.

```
spyOn(Person.prototype, 'getName');
// Call the method.
expect(Person.prototype.getName).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with this is that it involves me having to create a new instance of an object to test that particular object's methods/etc. I want to test the ones that are already getting instantiated via other means, so I can test to make sure their values are being updated, etc. I can't do this with a test object that I created that has no relation to the rest of my code.

Comment: @flysaiah Can you be more specific regarding how the objects are being instantiated, then?  A plunker would be helpful.  Is it possible for an instance of the composing object to be created in the test, for example in beforeEach()?  How does the composing object expose the object that you're trying to test?  As an aside, generally objects should be tested on their own if possible.  This makes unit testing much easier.  It's one of the major reasons (IMO) that developers stress dependency injection (and a major reason behind inversion of control patterns).

Comment: I see what you're saying. I've never done unit testing before, and I see now that my idea of what it is was completely flawed. Thanks for the insight about that.